# order fields inside CFS() loop wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'      => - 1,
        'post_type' => array('post-type-name'),
        'tax_query' => $taxquery,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'date_of_issue',
        'order' => 'DESC',  
);
global $post;
$post_list = get_posts($args);
if ($post_list) {
    foreach ($post_list as $post_item) { ?>
            <?php 
                $fields = CFS()->get('anouncements', $post_item->ID);
                if ( ! empty ( $fields ) ){
                    foreach ($fields as $field_eti) { ?>
                        <div class="item"><?php echo $field_eti['date_of_issue']; ?></div>
               <?php }
                } 
    ?>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I'm using Custom Field suite plugin. I want to order those fields by this date which is one of the custom fields of that loop (`$field_eti['date_of_issue'];`). How you see in my $args I added that meta_key and ordered it by custom field value which is date. But ordering isn't right.

Comment: Can you please make sure that the date that has been coming out of database is in YYYY-MM-DD format? If not, then there would not be any comparison of dates. So your order would not be as expected.

Comment: @Symbolwdd yes my date format is like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have updated my answer.

```
foreach ($post_list as $post_item) { 
setup_postdata($post_item);  // Set postdata
?>
            <?php 
                $fields = CFS()->get('anouncements');
                $temp=array();
                if ( ! empty ( $fields ) ){
                    foreach ($fields as $field_eti) { 
                               $temp[] = strtotime($field_eti['date_of_issue']);
?>

                        <div class="item"><?php echo $field_eti['date_of_issue']; ?></div>
               <?php }
               $new_field_eti[] = arsort($temp);
              print_r($new_field_eti);
                } 
    ?>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: @vrajesh - no it didn't help, ordering is still wrong.

Comment: @vrajesh see I have multiple posts and inside of each post I'm assigning custom field loop (loop has further title, text, customdate). And now I want to order these custom fields by that customdate

Comment: @aidaghazaryan i have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106982/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-vrajesh).